# Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()'

Tags: android, gradle, butterknife

I am trying to add the latest version of butterknife and I get this error from gradle:

> Error:(31, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of
>   Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
>
> The build file
>   may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply
>   Gradle plugin

Where my gradle `mobile` `build.gradle` is:

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.6"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mynamspace.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

**What's wrong with the gradle-apt-plugin?**

Comment: I haven't seen that `plugins` syntax before, and that does not appear to be the `android-apt` plugin.

Comment: That's the new mecanism of gradle plugins: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.ltgt.apt   (look for the "About the new plugin mechanism").

Comment: Where do I get the `android-apt` plugin?...I confess I am a bit lost here, I don't know much about gradle, I just got this plugin in a google search for "gradle apt"

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It's entirely possible that there's a way to get your `plugins` to work. Given your error, I'd start by following what the ButterKnife project uses, get that working, then see if there is a recipe for what you're trying.

First, in [your top-level `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/build.gradle), include `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` in the `buildscript` `dependencies`, such as:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
      classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
  }
```

Then, in [your module's `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife-sample/build.gradle), include `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` towards the top.

The links are to the relevant files from the ButterKnife GitHub repo, from the project and the dedicated sample app.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The project's page (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) have these configurations missing.....but the github page doesnt (https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) and they are pretty much the same as your code.

Comment: Coming from ButterKnife 7.0.1 to 8.0.1 - the upgrade was not at all obvious. All these extra Gradle entries were not explained very well at all. Finally have it working now thanks to your advice, @CommonsWare!

Comment: `apply at top` did it

Answer (score 20):

apt is obsolete, Change apt to new format:

change

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

to

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: this is for Android Gradle Plugin >= 2.2, if < 2.2 use the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
    plugins {id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.6"}
```

try:

```
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped:
adding to your `build.gradle` (not main, but project one) :

`apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

and

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your apt code into the apps build.gradle **NOT** in main build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    apt group: 'group name here', name: 'artifact name here', version:'version here'
}
```

Of Course, you'll have to add the following code in your main build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```