# ButterKnife Android: Unable to add Listener to View

Tags: android, binding, android-resources, butterknife

I added Butter knife library to Gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
   ...
}
```

Created a `Button` with id `btnPress`. In my Activity, when i tried to add method with `@onClick(R.id.btnPress)`, on running the application, the method does not execute.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.btnPress)
    Button btnPress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ButterKnife.bind(MainActivity.this);
    }

    //This method is not being called when Button is pressed.
    @OnClick(R.id.btnPress)
    void onPress() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: are you calling `setContentView` before calling `ButterKnife.Bind` ?
and make sure about your layout and views id.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Yes, i am setting View before binding. I have checked layout ids, they are same.

Comment: Did you add `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'` in your module-level `build.gradle` and `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` in your project-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Malwinder your issue is just with listeners? I mean is your `btnPress` correctly initialized or it's just `null` ?

Comment: @L.Meng I am receiving error: Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()'

Comment: @Malwinder Look at this [gradle-dsl-method-not-found-apt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876158/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-apt?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i resolved this issue:

First, in your top-level build.gradle file, include:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

in the buildscript dependencies, such as:

```
  buildscript {
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
      classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
  }
```

Then, in your module's build.gradle file, include `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` towards the top.

Now include ButterKnife library and compiler in module level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    ...
}
```