# ButterKnife - Gradle DSL method not found apt()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, butterknife

Getting this Error when attempting to add ButterKnife to my Gradle.

When attempting to just put..

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

In the Module:app

I get the error.. "Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()'

Following the answer outlined here - [Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876158/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-apt)

I place the...

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Into the Project gradle file, this produces the same 'apt()' error.

Finally, attempting to place

```
'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

and/or

```
'android-apt'
```

As outlined in the documentation - https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Now results in the same Gradle DSL method error, but this time 'apply()' instead of 'apt()'

How can I get this working?

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow.. it is useful answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37754907/3678308

Comment: Looks like that worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by following answer found here - [How to setup ButterKnife plugin in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754805/how-to-setup-butterknife-plugin-in-android-studio/37754907#37754907)

Credit goes to Waqar Younis (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3678308/waqar-younis) for comment provided above which linked to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please add this on top of your module level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

I also faced similar problem and resolved using this.